# Replace href on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select element with options with values that are some numbers (some id's).

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="21">Random<option>
    <option value="23">Random 2<option>
    <option value="25">Random 3<option>
    <option value="27">Random 4<option>
</select>
```

Next to it is a submit button that will preform some kind of submit.

```
<a class="button" href="www.random.org">Click me!</a>
```

I need to add the `?id=` to that link, with the id value of the select. I created the code, but the issue is that it just appends the `?id=` every time I change the select the option

```
var id;
$('#select').on('change', function(){
    id = $(this).val();
    var new_href = $('.button').attr('href') + '?id=' + id;
    $('.button').attr('href', new_href);
});
```

So when I click on first option I get, for the `href`

```
www.random.org?id=21
```

But if I click on second one (or any for that matter) I get

```
www.random.org?id=21?id=23
```

It appends the id. How to 'clear' the previous id on change, and replace with the selected one? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a data-attribute on the anchor tag. Instead of reading the URI from the `href` attribute, read from the data-attribute.

Comment: You could save the original href to a separate attribute, e.g. `data-href-orig="www.random.org"` and then set the href like this `$('.button').attr('href', $('.button').data('href-orig') + '?id=' + id);`.

Comment: Keep in mind that without a protocol (http|https) it will more than likely be treated as a relative URI and may not function properly.

Comment: The url is pulled from php (wordpress), I just simplified my problem to avoid including unnecessary explaining :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work.

```
var id;
var original_link = "www.random.org";
$('#select').on('change', function(){
    $('.button').attr('href', original_link);
    id = $(this).val();
    var new_href = $('.button').attr('href') + '?id=' + id;
    $('.button').attr('href', new_href);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying it, but now my id doesn't work. I'll look a bit, and see the issue, but this seems like it should work so I'll accept the answer in a little while.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this change button link

```
<a class="button" href="www.random.org" data-link="www.random.org">Click me!</a>
```

and change javascript like this

```
var id;
$('#select').on('change', function(){
    id = $(this).val();
    var new_href = $('.button').data('link') + '?id=' + id;
    $('.button').attr('href', new_href);
});
```

I think it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to [`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) function as second argument, where you can replace url for `.button`, like so

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
    var id   = $(this).val();

    $('.button').attr('href', function (index, value) {
        // if there is id in url - replace it, else add id to url
        return /\?id=/.test(value) ? value.replace(/id=(\d+)/, 'id=' + id) : (value + '?id=' + id);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zg5jn8j/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Respecting every other answer, I would prefer a small amount of code:

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
    $( '.button' ).attr( 'href', $( '.button' ).attr( 'href' ).split( '?id=' )[0] + '?id=' + $( this ).val() );
});
```

This code actually splits the `href` when a `?id=` exists and gives you only the part before it. When there is no `?id=` than you get the normal href and after this, you just add `?id=` and `$( this ).val()` to the href. (It's already in the code that I wrote)

That's it. No RegEx, Wordarounds or more lines of code than needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = $(".target");

$button = $(".button");
```

With jQuery you can `$target.attr('href', $button.data('href-url') + '?id=' + id))`

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/vh732rc6/1/)

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    var aLink = $('.button'),
        selVal = $(this).val(),
        staticLink = "www.random.org";
        //alert(selVal)
    $(aLink).attr('href', staticLink + "?id=" + selVal);    
})
```