# Pass dropdown value to onclick method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have a dropdown and link. I'm trying to pass selected dropdown value to onclick.

```
    <div>
        <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="venflows">
            <option value="marcus">marcus</option>
            <option value="bruno">bruno</option>
            <option value="jadon">jadon</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>



        <div>
            <a onclick="window.location.href = 'download/dropdown_selected_value_here'"></a>
        </div>
```

Here i'm trying to pass selected dropdown value to click.
Ex: if marcus is selected when onclick it should be like this

```
        <div>
            <a onclick="window.location.href = 'download/marcus'"></a>
        </div>
```

Ex: if bruno is selected when onclick it should be like this

```
        <div>
            <a onclick="window.location.href = 'download/bruno '"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: @RyanWilson You obviously are looking at the attempt

Comment: If OP knew how to change `dropdown_selected_value_here` to what he wanted, there would be no need to ask, would there?

Comment: `onclick="window.location.href = ` looks suspiciously like JavaScript to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace href on select change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643873/replace-href-on-select-change)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as posed

```
<a onclick="window.location.href = 'download/'+document.getElementById('venflows').value"></a>
```

But I recommend an eventListener

```js
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const url = `download/${document.getElementById("venflows").value}`
  console.log(url); // for testing
  this.href = url;
})
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="venflows">
    <option value="marcus">marcus</option>
    <option value="bruno">bruno</option>
    <option value="jadon">jadon</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="" id="link">GO</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want onclick event then you can try this

```
       <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="venflows" onclick="customFunction(this)">
            <option value="marcus">marcus</option>
            <option value="bruno">bruno</option>
            <option value="jadon">jadon</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
          
       <div>
            <a onclick="window.location.href = 'download/dropdown_selected_value_here'" id="url_nav"></a>
        </div>
     
        function customFunction(curObj){
            document.getElementById("url_nav").onclick = "window.location.href = 'download/'+curObj.value+"
        }
```

Comment: already updated the logic

Comment: document.getElementById("url_nav").onclick = function(curObj) { window.location.href = 'download/'+curObj.value;  }

Comment: Please do not use onclick AND inline click. It is REALLY confusing

Comment: customFunction has curObj as input parameter.

Comment: Yeah I saw it. It is not great

Comment: Yeah i know, that's the reason i kept "If you want onclick event then you can try this" .

Comment: You can make it better. There is no need to use event handlers on the select and onclick is not a good event handler on a select anyway

Comment: See my suggestion #1 for an onclick version